# UISearchbar and cellForRow

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am using UISearchBar in my app and it make search on UITableView.

i have a problem that when the app is in search mode it not make changes on the UITableView evan that the cellForRowAtIndexpath is called, any one have any idea why its happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is difficult to understand your problem in UITableview

but ,i have one great example of UITableview with Search bar and its operation.

I think this blog should help you..

http://www.xcode-tutorials.com/uitableview-%E2%80%93-4-searching-table-view/